# Image conversion from 24 bpp to 16 bpp format

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, windows-mobile, gdi

I have an image i.e. drawn using Windows GDI calls (24 bpp) and I need to convert this image to 16 bpp. This is on Windows Mobile.

```
 24 bpp - RGB (rrrrrrrr gggggggg bbbbbbbb)
 16 bpp - RGB (rrrrr gggggg bbbbb)
```

For this I am using the below code

```
for (int x = 0; x < iScreenSize; x++)
{
    *iPixel1= (*iPixel & 0x0000001F) |
              (*iPixel & 0x00003F00) >> 3 | 
              (*iPixel & 0x001F0000) >> 5;
}
```

The code works fine but the performance is not that good since I am modifying pixel by pixel.
Can you suggest any possible improvements to this conversion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend you to check out [Image magic API for c++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/)

Comment: Why are you masking the bottom bits of each color rather than the top? I can't believe you're getting acceptable output from that.

Comment: Looks like a fast algorithm to me.

Comment: I think there is no other way of doing this than going pixel by pixel. Are you using GetPixel() to retrieve each sample? If you are, [try using lockBits instead](http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm).

Comment: Instead of dereferencing iPixel three times, try using a local variable. I wouldn't be surprised if the optimizer already does this for you, though.

Comment: @Harish: Is your original 24bpp image packed? Or is each pixel aligned at a 32-bit boundary?

Comment: @SreenathNannat, Image Magic API doesn't seem to be supported on Windows mobile

Comment: @yms, I'm directly modifying the bytes from the void **ppvbits that is provided in the CreateDIBSection() API

Comment: @Emile, I am now using local variable and processing 4 pixels at a time and this seems to improve the performance by 30%. The pixels are aligned on a 32-bit boundary. I have created an image in the ARGB format but while converting I'm ignoring the transparency bit and converting the remaining 24 bits ti 16 bits.

Comment: @Mark, you are correct. I should mask the bottom bits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code isn't complete; you don't show the types of the pointers or how you're incrementing them. The number of operations you perform per pixel looks pretty optimal, so I'm going to guess that any slowness comes from unaligned memory access. You can fix this by unrolling the loop and doing 4 pixels at a time. Also the compiler should be smart enough to optimize multiple accesses to the same pointer, but lets assume it doesn't and copy them to temporary variables instead. I'm also going to assume you want to keep the upper bits of each color channel rather than the lower bits in your sample code.

```
UINT32 * iPixel;
UINT16 * iPixel1;
for (int x = 0; x < iScreenSize; x+=4)
{
    UINT32 dw1 = *iPixel++;
    UINT32 dw2 = *iPixel++;
    UINT32 dw3 = *iPixel++;
    *iPixel1++ = (dw1 & 0x000000F8) >> 3 |
                 (dw1 & 0x0000FC00) >> 5 |
                 (dw1 & 0x00F80000) >> 8;
    *iPixel1++ = (dw1 & 0xF8000000) >> 27 |
                 (dw2 & 0x000000FC) << 3 |
                 (dw2 & 0x0000F800);
    *iPixel1++ = (dw2 & 0x00F80000) >> 19 |
                 (dw2 & 0xFC000000) >> 21 |
                 (dw3 & 0x000000F8) << 8;
    *iPixel1++ = (dw3 & 0x0000F800) >> 11 |
                 (dw3 & 0x00FC0000) >> 13 |
                 (dw3 & 0xF8000000) >> 16;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, doing 4 pixels at a time improved the performance by 30%